# How do I curve-fit noisy data with a visible trend?

Tags: python, machine-learning, visualization

I have a graph that looks like this:
[image]

I want to do a curve fit on the exponential decay so that I can produce a model of the relationship.

I've tried multiple things to cut the noise, including instituting a floor and a ceiling value to remove outliers, checking the distribution of the data via box plot to see if the whole trend can be preserved by removing upper and lower quartiles (that one seems to work for 600 and beyond, but anything before fits into the upper quartile), and performing K-means clustering and plotting the centroids and attempting to fit on that. Nothing seems to work - the noise seems to be too high in amplitude to ignore for the curve-fitting algorithms.

I even tried making a simple linear neural network with relu / elu activations, and tried Huber and MSE losses, to no avail.

Here are the K-means centroids + median data plotted together under a log-transform, with an added line of best fit.

[image: K-means centroids + median data plotted together, added line of best fit.]

Comment: Is this a programming question or a signal processing question? [dsp](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.